# How to identify any application exe is launched or not?

Tags: labview

I want to know .exe file is getting properly launched or not?
I want a wrapper(in LabVIEW) to check whether the launching is done successfully  or not.

Thanks in Advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SysExec.vi to launch other applications from LabVIEW. You can refer this [link](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P821SAC&l=en-IN)

Then again use SysExec.vi with the command "cmd /c tasklist" to get the active application list. From the standard output you can find the target application.

Comment: Thanks! That was real quick

Comment: Hi, Did you try this before asking?